# Build Problems because of Error in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I'm using the JSP-mehtod `isUserInRole('Admin')` which Eclipse marks as an Error as follows `The method getIsUserInRole() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest`. It's red underlined, but the code works fine. The method at this path exists. What should I do and does it prevents building the project?

Comment: Please revise the signature of your request handle method, as it will never get invoked by the container.

Comment: Give us some details, at least stack trace of error. I think your application is not building. So not deployed to server. If there is ClassNotFoundException i think you missing some dependencies, for example commons-fileupload. But give us error detail, which class is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should mention following:

- In which case does it throws 404.
- For which class, it throws ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: For the UploadScript.java, when I try to call it from the HTML-form